# Gerar email aleatorios

Tags: javascript, random

Estou fazendo um exercício que estou quebrando cabeça, tenho que criar email aleatórios a partir de  array de objetos com dados de clientes fictícios, usando uma parte do `nome` e do `cpf` e não estou conseguindo, alguém poderia me explica uma forma de fazer.

```js
let clientes = [ 
    { nome: 'Kelvin Silva Sena', cpf: '10286741474', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Amyson Jhonata Da Silva', cpf: '10287054411', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Matheus Correa Da Silva', cpf: '10287259498', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Janekely Batista Dos Santos', cpf: '10288003470', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Luan Marcondes Alves De Souza', cpf: '10288469402', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Neidi Lucia Ignacio', cpf: '35331701949 ', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Neidi Lucia Ignacio ', cpf: '35331701949', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
    { nome: 'Neidi Lucia Ignacio', cpf: '35331701949', email: 'user@email.com.br', senha: 'passw:Abcd1234' },
]

//preciso criar uma função

function gerarEmail() {
    let dominios= ['@gmail.com', '@outlook.com', '@bol.com.br']
    //funcao para gerar email aleatorio com partes do nome + cpf
    //examplo linha 1: marl_102813arauj@outloo.com

}
```

Comment: e para que serve o array clientes?

Answer (score 1):

seguindo pelo seu array de clientes...

```
function gerarEmail() {
    let dominios= ['@gmail.com', '@outlook.com', '@bol.com.br']
    for(var i=0;i<clientes.length;i++){
        let label   = clientes[i].nome.split(' ');
        let email   = label[0]+clientes[i].cpf+dominios[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
       dominios.length)];
        document.write(email+"<br/>");    
    }
 }

 gerarEmail();
```

Montei um loop **FOR** para iterar sobre cada cliente de sua listagem, em seguida usei o **split** do javascript quebrando a string de nome de cada cliente entre espaços, gerando um array que aqui foi nomeado como label. Concatenei a primeira posição desse array, que compreende como o primeiro nome de cada cliente com o cpf inteiro. Em seguida apenas gerei um número randômico que comprende de zero até o total de itens de seu array domínios, concatenando na variavel string **email**. Por último eu mandei imprimir quebrando uma linha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]